# If and Else are both executed when the code is executed

Tags: php, cakephp

PHP Version: 7.3.8
CakePHP Version: 4.0.1
Database Server: 10.4.6-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Web server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c

**// WHAT I'M DOING**

I created an error recording function to compliment the comprehensive error reporting functionality that comes out of the box with Cake. It's purpose in development is to assist me in reducing the amount of time it takes me to isolate an error when it occurs. And it's purpose when my app goes live is to do the same as in development but also assist me in monitoring any security vulnerabilities.

**// WHAT'S HAPPENING:**

Between 6 and 9 errors are being recorded in the database but the function that records the error is housed in the if part of the statement.

**// USERS CONTROLLER**

```
public function view(string $userID = null): void
{
    // Initialise the variables.
    $this->args = func_num_args();
    $this->params = func_get_args();

    if ($this->args !== 1) {

        echo 'in FAILED ' . '<br /><br />';

        // THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT RECORDS THE ERROR.
        $this->setErrorLocation(
            $this->controller(). ' - Line ' . __LINE__);
        if ($this->recordError(
            $this->getErrorLocation()) === false) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    else {

        // BUT THIS IS WHATS PRINTED TO THE SCREEN.
        echo 'in PASSED ' . '<br /><br />';
    }

   // Rest of view code...
}
```

When the above code is executed the else part of the statement is executed and 'in PASSED' is printed to the screen. This is the expected behaviour.

And this is the unexpected behaviour:

1. Between 6 and 9 errors are recorded in the database?
2. 'in FAILED' is NOT printed to the screen?
3. No exception is thrown?

======================================================================

**// CODE TO REPLICATE**

I've streamlined the code to the bare bones to hopefully enable replication of the behaviour.

**// APP CONTROLLER**

**// The record error function:**

The idea behind this function is best case scenerio I get a log in my database and Cake logs the error and throws an exception and worst case scenerio is Cake logs the error and throws an exception.

```
public function recordError(string $errorLocation): bool
{
    // Initialise the variables.
    $this->args = func_num_args();
    $this->params = func_get_args();

    // Check the number of arguments.
    if ($this->args !== 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check the argument type.
    if (!is_string($this->params[0])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Insert into the database.
    $Errors = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Errors');
    $error = $Errors->newEmptyEntity();
    $error->ip = '::1';
    $error->user_id = 1001; // NOTE: This must be a valid id so if $rules->existsIn is present in the user model the save does not fail.
    $error->location = $this->params[0];
    $error->date_occurred = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

    // Save the error.
    if ($Errors->save($error)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**// The error location setter and getter.**

```
protected function setErrorLocation(string $errorLocation): object
{
    $this->errorLocation = $errorLocation;

    return $this;
}
protected function getErrorLocation(): string
{
    return $this->errorLocation;
}
```

**// USERS CONTROLLER**

**The controller name**

```
private function controller(): string
{
    $val = 'UsersController';
    return $val;
}
```

**// DATABASE**

```
Table name: errors

Name           Type            Collation              Attributes   Null   Default
id Primary     int(10)                                              No      None        AUTO_INCREMENT
ip             varchar(100)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci                   No      None
user_id        int(10)                                              No      None
location       varchar(200)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci                   No      None
date_occured   datetime                                             No      None
```

======================================================================

**// RELEVANT INFO**

The majority of the time this function works as expected but in the controllers view, edit and index methods multiple errors are being recorded.

I use this technique several times in view, edit and index and its only on a couple of instances does it not work as expected.

Also it's not just when I use PHP argument functions, it also records multiple errors in index when I use is_string.

I'm not sure if it's my environment, PHP, Cake or something I'm doing.

======================================================================

**// MY QUESTION**

Why are the errors recorded in the database?

(I mean how can the errors be recorded unyet no exception is thrown and in PASSED is printed to the screen?)

Thanks Zenzs.

======================================================================

@Jeto

I used the below backtrace function and it prints the following:

```
$e = new \Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
```

string(3679) "

0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(524): App\Controller\UsersController->view('1026')

1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php(79): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction(Object(Closure), Array)

2 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php(229): Cake\Controller\ControllerFactory->invoke(Object(App\Controller\UsersController))

3 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(77): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

4 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\authentication\src\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware.php(122): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

5 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

6 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\I18n\Middleware\LocaleSelectorMiddleware.php(70): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

7 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Cake\I18n\Middleware\LocaleSelectorMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

8 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(77): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

9 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php(132): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

10 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

11 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(58): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

12 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php(162): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

13 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

14 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php(68): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

15 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

16 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(118): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

17 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

18 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware.php(60): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

19 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(73): DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))

20 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(58): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))

21 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php(90): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(App\Application))

22 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\webroot\index.php(40): Cake\Http\Server->run()

23 {main}"

---

XDebug is an excellent suggestion but as yet I have not installed it but it's on my list.

And this comment helps me understand a little more:
It could easily be that some of the calls fall in the error case and one of them passes.

Thanks.

======================================================================

@ndm

I'm using Chrome and it is making multiple requests but only to the ones in the head section of my app. I can't see any requests for any other than the ones it should be. IE: Requests to the following because all the following are stored locally:

```
<script src="bootstrap-sass/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-sass/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-sass/javascripts/crm-sys.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet "href="bootstrap-sass/stylesheets/all.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-sass/stylesheets/sys-styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

Due to the fact that I installed [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) which complies my sass I have a slightly different webroot structure. IE:

```
webroot
    ->bootstrap-sass
        ->.sass-cache
        ->fonts
        ->javascripts
        ->sass
        ->stylesheets
        ->webfonts
        config.rb
    ->css
    ->font
    ->img
    ->js
```

IE: I don't store my stylesheets in the Cake default css folder. I'm not sure if I can recompile it so it does but I thought I'd save that job for just before I go live.

**A POSSIBLE ANSWER:**

Chrome doesn't make requests to anything it shouldn't be but because I use compass I have to traverse the directory to ensure the files can be found on index, add, view and edit and Chrome confirms it makes multiple requests for the same file.

And I have to declare each of the above links 3 times like below and Chrome confirms it's making 3 requests for each file.

```
<!-- Welcome and index etc -->
<script src="bootstrap-sass/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add -->
<script src="../bootstrap-sass/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- View and edit -->
<script src="../../bootstrap-sass/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could this be the cause of the behaviour I'm seeing?

I think that might be it because the multiple entries in the database are always either an extra 3, 6, 9. Ie: Always grouped in threes and it's a bit coincidental that I declare each file 3 times and the user agent confirms its making 3 requests.

Surely that's got to be it. Would you agree?

---

Also thanks for the heads up about not echoing data from the controller. Can I confirm you mean I should write to a flat file or even to the db.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `view` called once per script/page execution? It could easily be that some of the calls fall in the error case and one of them passes. Try debugging more, ideally using (XDebug) breakpoints, or else using simple debugging functions such as `var_dump` or `debug_print_backtrace`.

Comment: Obviously the code is being invoked multiple times, it's impossible for an if/else statement to execute both branches. Start with checking whether your user agent is issuing multiple requests. Also note that controllers should never echo data, that can lead to all sorts of problems, log your debugging data to a file instead.

Comment: Whether your multiple asset inclusion stuff is the problem, I can't really tell, as I'm not sure how the user controller would be invoked by that, but since you see multiple of 3's, it surely sounds possible, or at least related. I would suggest that you use the HTML helper provided by CakePHP for generating your asset tags, and use a root relative path, that is, prefix your path with a `/`, CakePHP will handle the rest, and prepend the base path if required, so no multiple variants are required.

Comment: ps, it's better to use comments and tag people to respond to them, usually people don't monitor questions all the time so that they would see your updates.

Comment: @ndm I'm with you on sounds possible/related...And I will configure a helper to generate the asset tags for the reasons stated. I'll probably do that just before I go live as I've still got to actually finish building the app.

Comment: @ndm Never realised the person tag only worked on comments, I'll be sure to do that in future and thanks for your suggestions and help.